# Howto access codeplex with svn

Tags: svn, codeplex

the documentation says to find the svn url on the Source Code tab but there is no svn url anywhere to be found. All I see is a Mercurial URL in the popup.

Am I missing something?

The codeplex project I am looking to connect to is http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/Forks/RabbiPlotkin/FacebookSDK613

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the project started out as a SVN project but was later converted to Mercurial.